# Unit test in golang with structure

Tags: go

I use the VSCode generation for test file of my project,

currenlty it generate the folloing structure

```
tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        wantOut ZTR
    }{
        name: "test123",
        args: args{
            ztrFile: "./testdata/ztrfile.yaml",
        },
        wantOut: “ZTR.Modules",
    }
```

The test should cover parse of yaml and testing the properties

Here it calles to parse file

```
for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if gotOut := parseFile(tt.args.ztrFile); !reflect.DeepEqual(gotOut, tt.wantOut) {
                t.Errorf("parseFile() = %v, want %v", gotOut, tt.wantOut)
            }
        })
```

This is the struct

```
type Modules struct {
    Name       string
    Type       string
    cwd       string     `yaml:”cwd,omitempty"`
}
```

Not sure what I need to put here to make it work, I try to play with the types but Im getting errors

```
        {
            name: "test123",
            args: args{
                mtaFile: "./testdata/ztrfile.yaml",
            },
            wantOut: “ZTR.Modules",
        }
```

The errors I got is

message: 'cannot use "test123" (type string) as type struct { name string; args args; wantOut ZTR } in array or slice literal'
at: '41,3'
source: ''
code: 'undefined'

Comment: Which is line 41 of your source?

Comment: @Flimzy - `name: "test123”,` and I’ve also error on `wantOut: “ZTR.Modules”,`

Comment: You're missing some braces. Remember, you're giving it *entries in a slice of structs*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tests` declaration is incorrect.  You need to provide a slice of structs, but you're providing just keys/values:

```
tests := []struct {
    name    string
    args    args
    wantOut ZTR
}{
    name: "test123",
    args: args{
        mtaFile: "./testdata/ztrfile.yaml",
    },
    wantOut: “ZTR.Modules",
}
```

should be:

```
tests := []struct {
    name    string
    args    args
    wantOut ZTR
}{
    {
        name: "test123",
        args: args{
            mtaFile: "./testdata/ztrfile.yaml",
        },
        wantOut: “ZTR.Modules",
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solve the issue, last question now I’ve error in the `wantOut` , what I should put there ? for example if the name of the `modules` should be like `name=“just name”` `type=“justType”`

Comment: I usderstad that this is what I want to verify `expected` but how should I put it there ?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing what the error is.

Comment: if I need to verify the output of the parse of the structure, how should I put it there , any example will help

Comment: When I put `wantOut: Modules,` I got error `type module is not expression`